# Cannot execute boolean operation

Tags: modifiers

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50320

I am using the testing ring as the **difference** (what I am removing)

The plane (haven't got to naming it) as the **subject** (Be removed from)

It won't let me use the modifier. I have tried recalculating the normals I have also tried it without the face in the center of the testing ring extruding the bottom face of the plane and and the testing ring by zero

Would appreciate the help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYbRd.jpg

Comment: If you elaborate on what you have tried and what you are shooting for (pictures help), you will find better engagement with your question.

Comment: well, the boolean works but your topology is very bad, a lot of faces overlapping etc...

Comment: I agree with moonboots

Comment: #Kirbinator Sorry I added that info now (well the best I could) #Moonboots and WhatAMesh well what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @CarolineLewis If you want to notify user use @ before his name (not #)

Comment: @Crantisz Sorry I'll do that from now on. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean modifier works with volumes, It will not work with 2D shapes, flat forms, one-sided geometry.

So first, you need to add some volume to your object:

[image]

So, I guess, you have a trouble with proportional editing is on, turn it off by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> and move one face up to make a volume. And select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>N</kbd> just to make sure, that normals are correct.

Then edit a ring. Remove central faces inside the ring and add 2 face on top and the bottom like this:

[image]

This makes you boolean works.